# split NSString with syllables

Tags: objective-c, ios6

How to split the syllables in a NSString using Objective-c. Is there any API for that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is syllables, Water has two syllables wa+ter... please explain.

Comment: yes for exemple objective-c --> ob+jec+tive+-c

Comment: can I suggest to break based on vowels?

Comment: So if this is almost impossible what else you planning?

Comment: my idea is to divise all the words in syllabes like this: when i found a voyel, i will put the rest of the word in the next line(that almost right in frensh) , and i will save all the syllabes in an array, and then i will write them in my botton..what do u think :)

Comment: You can do, but `Objective-c` will become `O + bje + cti + ve + -c` is it fine for you? should I give solution for this?

Comment: no it will be fine Objective-c become O + bje + cti + ve + -c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOOO, It cant be.

As Syllables are not in fixed way. There are no patterns to check.

And programming is done to automate things, even AI is implemented when there are something common, unique in any manner.

Water is to broken into Wa + ter.

Objective-c is to be broken into Ob + jec + tive-c.

This makes no [algorithm](http://www.aistudy.com/program/prolog/visual_prolog/Dividing%20Words%20into%20Syllables.htm) to perform and automate the task using any of the API of obj-C.

EDIT:

As per your comments, find the code:

```
NSString *word=@"encyclopedia";
NSString *formattedWord=word;
for (NSString *vowel in @[@"a",@"e",@"i",@"o",@"u",@"A",@"E",@"I",@"O",@"U"]) {
    formattedWord=[formattedWord stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:vowel withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<<<%@",vowel]];
}    
NSArray *brokenWord=[formattedWord componentsSeparatedByString:@"<<<"];

NSString *syllables=[brokenWord componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];

NSLog(@"Syllables of %@ are %@",word,syllables);
```